# Flex/AIR pinch zoom centreing image

Tags: apache-flex, air, zooming, pinch

I am developing an application with flex/air and I need to centre an image in the view port while pinch zooming.

I start with an image of 3008x2000 at 1:1 scale, I then want to be able to zoom in and out on a certain area of the image with a combination of scaling and repositioning on the screen.

Does anybody have a working method of doing this smoothly? I keep messing with the math but am having no luck.

Comment: Hi Hamid, I think you're going to need to use the matrix :) love saying that but it's true.  I imagine your goal here is to scale based on relative position of touch points from the time of contact of a second point to the time of release of either point and you'll want to re-position based on the location between the two points initially (this is just my guess on the interaction, explanation is welcome). http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=15_Geometry_5.html if you can explain the interaction more I'll give this a shot, sounds like a fun problem.

Comment: Yes, I think matrices are the solution but my math isn't the best, essentially, I have a 30008x2000 image, to which the viewport is 1024x600, and when pinch-zoom is done I want to "zoom-in" to the pinched area, just as you expect in every other pinch zoom application.

Comment: I created a blogpost for pinchzoom on a touch device with AIR at http://blog.simplecode.eu/2012/12/24/PinchzoomImageWithAdobeAir.aspx